# ID3 Frame Header

Tags: c++, id3

I want to try to read ID3 tags on my own without a library for educational purpose. I have to do a presentation for school on how to do it.

First I read the ID3 header (first 10 bytes). It works. Now I try to read the first Frame Header which is in almost all my files following directly after the ID3 Header. So there is no extended header. The Frame Header should be 10 bytes as well, right? Well then I have a problem.

The Frame Header in all the files I checked are structured as followed:

```
+------------+   
-  Frame ID  -   
+------------+   
- Frame Size -   
+------------+   
- Frame Flags-   
+------------+
```

After that the value should follow, right? If the id is TALB (Album) it should be the albums name. And the value should be the size of the frame size's value. However, all my files have a `0x03` before the album name, actually before all frames, and the frame size is also 1 higher. Example:

Frame ID = TIT2
Frame Size = 13(12+1 for the 0x03)
Flags ...
Value = (0x03 character)3 Doors Down

What does that value mean? I read a little bit about text encoding and this value would be:

> $03   UTF-8 [UTF-8] encoded Unicode [UNICODE]. Terminated with $00.

But I did not see any part where this text encoding value is placed at.

This is my code(simplified) to read the frame header its value:

```
//Method from a FrameHeader Class, takes 10 bytes as parameter
void setHeader( char* value ){

    int i = 0;
    for(; i < 4; i++ ){
        identifier += value[i];
    }

    for(; i < 8; i++ ){
        size = size << 8 | static_cast<unsigned char>(value[i]);
    }

    for(; i < 10; i++ ){
        flags += value[i];
    }
}

memblock = new char[10];
iStream.read( memblock, 10 );

FrameHeader frameHeader;
frameHeader.setHeader( memblock );

memblock = new char[ frameHeader.getSize() ];
iStream.read( memblock, frameHeader.getSize() );

cout << "Frame Indentifier : " << frameHeader.getIdentifier() << endl;
cout << "Frame Size : " << frameHeader.getSize() << endl;
cout << "Frame value : " << memblock << endl;*/
```

I hope my problem is clear. I cannot upload the file since it is a song which is copyrighted and I would get in trouble with the law doing so.

I got all the information from this [source](http://id3.org/id3v2.4.0-structure).

Comment: The `0x03` before the text is the "encoding byte". `0x03` incicates UTF-8. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3#ID3v2

Answer (score 3):

The byte you have found is an encoding byte. From [id3v2.4.0-structure.txt](http://id3.org/id3v2.4.0-structure):

> Frames that allow different types of text encoding contains a text
>   encoding description byte. Possible encodings:
>
> ```
>  $00   ISO-8859-1 [ISO-8859-1]. Terminated with $00.
>  $01   UTF-16 [UTF-16] encoded Unicode [UNICODE] with BOM. All
>        strings in the same frame SHALL have the same byteorder.
>        Terminated with $00 00.
>  $02   UTF-16BE [UTF-16] encoded Unicode [UNICODE] without BOM.
>        Terminated with $00 00.
>  $03   UTF-8 [UTF-8] encoded Unicode [UNICODE]. Terminated with $00.
> ```

And:

> Strings dependent on encoding are represented in frame descriptions
>   as *text string according to encoding*, or *full text string
>
>   according to encoding* if newlines are allowed. Any empty strings of
>   type $01 which are NULL-terminated may have the Unicode BOM followed
>   by a Unicode NULL ($FF FE 00 00 or $FE FF 00 00).

In addition to the structure document you need to be referring to the [frame descriptions document](http://id3.org/id3v2.4.0-frames), which will tell you how the frame is structured. TIT2 is a text frame. The frame description for TIT2 is under  *Section 4.2. Text information frames*, and it shows that a Text Encoding byte should be present:

> Header for 'Text information frame', ID: "T000" - "TZZZ",
>        excluding "TXXX" described in 4.2.6.
>
> ```
>  Text encoding                $xx
>
>  Information                  text string(s) according to encoding
> ```

Essentially, you need to refer to these 2 documents together as some frames have this byte and some don't, and some frames (if you were to implement them) require very special handling indeed. Look, for example, at the APIC frame which allows the embedding of art into the tag.

It may be worth pointing out that writing a full and feature complete ID3V2 decoder is a major task (I've been there). There are [several versions](http://id3.org/Developer%20Information) of the standard - and tags made with each version of the standard *do* exist in the wild; not to mention such options as encryption, compression and [unsynchronisation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19671469/397817), and the issue of [tags made by broken encoders](http://id3.org/Compliance%20Issues). For a project like yours, I would just implement reading of a few of the most common frames. If you're also writing tags, just take care to write out verbatim any frames you haven't implemented the reading of.

In addition to the quoted resources, the [Wikipedia article on ID3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3) may also be useful.

Answer (score 0):

From your linked page:

> Frames that allow different types of text encoding contains a text encoding description byte. Possible encodings:
>
> $00   ISO-8859-1 [ISO-8859-1]. Terminated with $00.
>
> $01   UTF-16 [UTF-16] encoded Unicode [UNICODE] with BOM. All
>              strings in the same frame SHALL have the same byteorder.
>              Terminated with $00 00.
>
> $02   UTF-16BE [UTF-16] encoded Unicode [UNICODE] without BOM.
>              Terminated with $00 00.
>
> $03   UTF-8 [UTF-8] encoded Unicode [UNICODE]. Terminated with $00.

That means that the first byte of a string field of type **text string according to encoding** will always be one of these bytes, and that byte will select the encoding used for the text. But you will not find the name of the encoding literally.

Note that there are aso fields of type **text string** that lack that byte and assume ISO-8859-1.

In your file, the `0x03` means that the following text is UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: You said the first byte of a string field. Is it possible that there is no string field?

Comment: @Davlog: Just following my cite, it says that this is the proper way to do fields of type _text string according to encoding_, (cf. with simple _text string_). However, since none of these bytes is likely to appear as a proper character, I would program a fallback, in case there is no encoding byte, just in case. For such sloppy-created tags I would assume the same encoding as in simple text strings: ISO-8859-1.